# Ruby Resque , @queue instance varaible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque, attr-accessor

I am a newbie and just started learning ruby. I find [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) amazing but am faced with a question when reading the documentation.

We define a `@queue` instance variable inside a job class without defining any `attr_reader`, so how can a worker find the value of this instance variable later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby does not provide true isolation of instance variables- it is more of a recommendation. So private instance variables of an object can actually be accessed by other objects through multiple means like [`instance_variable_get`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get), [`instance_eval`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_eval)  etc.

Resque uses [`instance_variable_get`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get) to extract the queue name from instance variable.

The relevant source is [here](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/9c023f8c12f7e31caf8b7a73ae5094934a0ddf17/lib/resque.rb#L412).